# Update trigger AWS Lambda [NodeJS SDK]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to update programmatically (from a lambda function) the trigger of a (another) lambda function ?

**UPDATE** : more precisely the trigger is a Schedule Event (cron)

I found some [actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/) like change the code or the runtime but didn't see anything concerning the trigger.

Comment: By "trigger" do you mean scheduled invocations? DynamoDB or Kinesis triggers? The answer is going to be different depending on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Scheduled Events exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheduled events fall under the CloudWatch service. That's why you aren't seeing them under the Lambda SDK. You have to create or update the CloudWatch Event that points to a Lambda target.

You didn't specify what language/SDK you are using, but [this is the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html) for CloudWatch Events in the NodeJS SDK. It should be easy to find the corresponding documentation for whatever language/SDK you are using.

[Here is official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) showing how to update Lambda scheduled events via the AWS CLI.